# Can't get carousel slider to work with meteor

Tags: css, meteor, carousel

I want to implement carousel slider gallery on my portfolio page that im creating with Meteor.

The issue is that I can only get to work one gallery but the second one doesnt load correctly, it just lists the pictures.

Heres the problem in picture
[image: Heres the problem in picture]

My code is here:

```
#carousel {
  border:   1px solid black;
  width:    200px;
  position: relaitve;
  top:      100px;
  left:     100px;
}

#carousel div {
  width:    200px;
}

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
  color:    silver;
}


<template name="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cold-md-1">
        <div id="carousel">
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/jaanikapirjophotography_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/GreteKlein_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/spring_banquet_by_heidishvili-d572cf0_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/dawning_by_heidishvili-d368ld9_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cold-md-1">
        <div id="carousel">
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/jaanikapirjophotography_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/GreteKlein_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/spring_banquet_by_heidishvili-d572cf0_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
          <div><img src="http://heidipahn.edicy.co/photos/dawning_by_heidishvili-d368ld9_large.jpg" width="200px" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.portfolio.rendered = function() {
    $('#carousel').slick({
      dots: true,
      arrows: true
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved now. Problem was I was using the CSS ID-s not classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a wrong css class for columns. It should be

> div class="col-md-1"

instead of

> div class="cold-md-1"